# Can't chroot users correctly with vsftpd

Tags: chroot, vsftpd

I used [this tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-raspberry-pi/) to install vsftp.

Everything seems to work fine except for two things:

1. Even though I set `local_root=/home/$USER/ftp` the default location
   when I use any ftp-client is /home/$USER.
2. I have read access to the
   entire file-system.

I assume they are related but I can't be sure. I tried fixing this in various ways, but I just can't get this figured out. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me.

Here is my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf

# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.

# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.


# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO

# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES

# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO

# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES

# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES

# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022

# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES

# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES

# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES

# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES

# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES

# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever

# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES

# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600

# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120

# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure

# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES

# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES

# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.

# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails

# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp

# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES

# Customization

# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.

# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd

# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES

# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
utf8_filesystem=YES

# FTP passive mode port ranges.
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=31000

# This option is to permit only certain users to log in.
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
userlist_deny=NO
```

Comment: did you confirm that /home/$USER/ftp is a directory and not a symlink to /?    Also, did you confirm that there are no old vsftpd daemons still running after making the configuration change?

Comment: I did confirm both of these.

Comment: I used your configuration as is on my vsftpd server and it worked as expected.

Comment: It's nice to know that my config file works on your server. However, if the config file is correct, the next question becomes: what else could be wrong for this to happen? I can't think of anything.

Comment: As a test I just renamed the vsftpd.conf file and restarted the service. Nothing has changed. Mabye there is a differenc conf file somewhere I'm not aware off.

Comment: Ran a search; no other suspicious files with this name found.

Comment: are you specifying the config file as a command line parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trail and error, I found the error: there was a different FTP client installed on this machine, and I wasn't aware of this. I figured it out after removing vsftpd and realizing it still worked. @toppk thanks for trying to help; sorry for wasting your time!

EDIT: So apparently when you enable SSH it will also enable the build in SSH server automatically. It's called 'openssh-sftp-server' and you can find it using the command: `sudo apt list --installed | grep ftp`. Disabling SSH corrects this issue.

Comment: I understant that vsftpd cannot chroot users from local accounts...